# Mac OS X Lion donesn't start after Windows 8 installing

Tags: macos, osx-lion, windows-8-preview

I'm having some troubles booting from Mac OS X Lion after installing Windows 8 Release Preview on bootcamp partition.

I've made these steps.

1. Install Windows 8 Consumer Preview using bootcamp
2. Upgrade Windows 8 Consumer Preview to Release Preview
3. Reboot the system and hold option key.
4. On bootcamp select Machintosh HD
5. Mac OS X Lion doesn't start, or after a lot of time, it presents me the accounts screen but I cannot select anyone, trackpad or keyboard doesn't works!

I tried to boot from Recovery HD, but keyboard and trackpack doesn't work too.

I tried to boot from Snow Leopard installation CD, but it also doesn't work.

If I restart and boot in Windows 8, everything works fine!

I have a Macbook Pro 15".

Could someone helps me?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", you just mean keyboard and trackpad right?

Comment: Right! But at last I could make it work on an easy way. I restarted NVRam holding Command+Option+P+R and everything goes well again and I could restore my Time Machine backup

Comment: Hooray! Glad you fixed it.

Comment: You should put your solution in as an answer.